# JSON file contents in docker container are not reflecting correct changes

Tags: python, json, docker, fastapi, uvicorn

I am using fast api to create endpoints. There are 3 basic endpoints:

1. /create to add a record in json file
2. /delete to delete a record in json file
3. /view which displays the record from json file

This json file is called store.json. This functionality is working fine when triggering the uvicorn server locally. But after containerizing it with docker the modification done to this file is not happening correctly. For example while adding records some records are not written in the file.

Below are the code snippets:

/view

```
@router.get("/")
async def view():
    """
    Fetched the list
    """
    resp = get_records()
    return {"response": resp}


def get_records():
    with open("core/store/store.json") as store_file:
        store = json.load(store_file)
    return store
```

/create

```
@router.get("/create")
async def create():
    """
    Create the record
    """
    resp = create_records()
    return {"response": resp}


def create_records():
    with open("core/store/store.json") as store_file:
        store = json.load(store_file)
    store.get("students").append({
        "id": random.randint(1, 101),
        "date_created": datetime.now().strftime("%b-%d-%Y at %H:%M")
    })
    with open("core/store/store.json", "w") as outfile:
        json.dump(store, outfile)
    return store.get("students")[-1]
```

/delete

```
@router.get("/delete{id}")
async def delete(id):
    """
    Delete the record
    """
    resp = del_records(id)
    return {"response": resp}


def del_records(id):
    with open("core/store/store.json") as store_file:
        store = json.load(store_file)
    for info in store.get("students"):
        if info.get("id") == id:
            store.get("students").remove(info)
            break
    with open("core/store/store.json", "w") as outfile:
        json.dump(store, outfile)
    return f"deleted id {id}"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    python -m pip install --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 4558

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "4558", "--workers", "4"]
```

Docker version

```
>> docker --version
Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57
```

Comment: I would expect a syntax error for the missing quote, and once you fix that, a file not found for the JSON file. There are too many things wrong here to focus on; voting to close as lacking debugging details.

Comment: @tripleee added the quote which got missed while copying. The JSON file path is the core/store/strore.json in the container itself and is able to access the file. The main point here is that the editing in the file is not happening properly. This is only seen when running the app as a container.

Comment: Nothing here creates the directory where the file should be, so perhaps then you are obscuring this by hiding relevant parts of the code.

Comment: Generating random `id` numbers also means you could create inadvertent duplicates. Is this an early proof of concept where this is acceptable, or a bug?

Comment: This is an early POC where it is fine to be that way.

Comment: Still, please review the guidance for providing a [mre]. How exactly are you concluding that the JSON file is not being updated correctly? Is this file included in the `COPY` step?

Comment: the initial json file is in the project structure in the location core/store/store.json which is included in the Dockerfile line `COPY . /app`, post which the app is run via container and the modifications in the file are made via these endpoints.

I cross checked the contents of the json file from inside the container after each create request and found that certain records are not reflected in the file.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing missing writes since you're running with multiple workers (`--workers 4`), and your code is prone to race conditions.

Consider the case where you have two workers running e.g. `create_records`, here described as a primitive concurrency diagram, time running downwards:

| Worker 1 | Worker 2 |
| --- | --- |
| receive request | ... |
| open json (0 entries: []) | receive request |
| add data [123] | open json (0 entries: []) |
| save json ([123]) | add data [456] |
| ... | save json ([456]) |
| receive request | ... |
| open json (1 entries: [456]) | ... |

Only `456` will have ended up in the final file since worker 2 will not know about `123` by the time it's saving the file.

Your options are basically to:

- Lock the file while it's being modified, leading to only one worker being able to manipulate the file at any given time (depending on what you're doing, this could be okay)
- Switch to a more robust storage backend

  - For instance, separate JSON files per record (i.e. your database is a directory of JSON files) can be atomically manipulated.
  - If that's too cumbersome, Sqlite would be a decent next step.

Comment: I second using sqlite. Way more solid than json files.

Comment: I was also thinking the same but the same uvicorn command when i run it to start the app without any docker the reading and writing works just fine.

Comment: Are you making exactly the same sequence of requests with exactly the same concurrency and timing?

Comment: yes I am following the same pattern.